# Radius of circle around rectangle corner

Tags: polynomial-math

I'm trying to calculate the radius of a circle from the center of a rectangle, that reaches the edge of a circle with the radius of 575' from the rectangle's corner.  See below, given the rectangle is 475' x 230', and each corner of the rectangle has a circle with a 575' radius.  What is the radius from the center of the rectangle to the edge of those circles?

Rectangle 475 x 230, each corner has a circle with a radius of 575..  Need to calculate the radius from the center of the rectangle that reaches the outermost edge of each corner's circles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outermost edge of each circle's corner is the circle's radius (575) plus the distance from the centre of the rectangle to the corner ( sqrt( (475/2)^2 * (230/2)^2 = 263.88) distant from the centre of the rectangle, so your distance/radius is 838.88